# How does this version of findViewById() work?

Tags: java, android, generics, annotations, findviewbyid

[This version](https://www.techyourchance.com/casting-android-views/) of [`View.findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) returns the most specific concrete subtype of `View`:

```
protected <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) getRootView().findViewById(id);
}
```

**How does it work?** Specifically, how can the type be inferred at compile-time when the `id` is looked up at runtime? Does it have to do with the annotation?

This differs from questions with similar titles, which are about the *use* of `findViewById()`:

- [No need to cast the result of findViewById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid)
- [How does findViewById work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357734/how-does-findviewbyid-work)
- [Android O casting to findViewById not needed anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092494/android-o-casting-to-findviewbyid-not-needed-anymore)

I would like to know *why* it works.

Comment: `findViewById()` returns a View Object. That Object is then cast to whatever T is determined to be. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be inferred. It uses a cast - `return (T)`. The caller is responsible for ensuring that the type T matches the type of view being located. If they get this wrong, the operation will fail with a `ClassCastException`.

The type can be either explicitly specified, i.e.

```
this.<TextView>findViewById(R.id.someTextView)
```

(excuse my syntax if I've got this wrong - I mostly deal in Kotlin now)

or it can be inferred from the destination:

```
TextView foundView = findViewById(R.id.someTextView)
```

but in either case, the responsibility lies with the caller.

The Android toolchain may do further work to cross-reference layout XML with the code, and produce warnings or failures within your IDE, but this is a compile-time layer on top of what Java performs at runtime.

It has nothing to do with the `@IdRes` annotation, which is there to assert - again at compile time - that the `id` parameter is a reference to the ID of some XML-based entity, and not simply any integer value.

Comment: Thank you! What I was missing was that it could be inferred from the destination.